# Sharing code between specialized and unspecialized templated struct

Tags: c++, templates

How might I share code between a specialized and unspecialized version of a C++ class?

Here's a contrived example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <size_t n> struct Y {
    int one() { return 1; }
    int two();
};

template <> struct Y<1> {
    int one() { return 11; }
    int two();
};

template <size_t n> int Y<n>::two() { return one() * 2; }

int main() {
    Y<1> X;
    cout << X.one();
    cout << X.two();
    return 0;
}
```

This fails at link time with:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Y<1ul>::two()", referenced from:
      _main in test-7c4ebe.o
```

However, if I change the `Y<1> X;` to `Y<2> X;`, compilation succeeds just fine.

My goal here was the use the sample implementation of `two()` for the specialized and unspecialized version of the class.

I was able to get around this problem with inheritance like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct mixin {
    virtual int one() = 0;
    int two() { return one() * 2; }
};

template <size_t n> struct Y : public mixin {
    int one() { return 1; }
};

template <> struct Y<1> : public mixin {
    int one() { return 11; }
};

int main() {
    Y<1> X;
    cout << X.one();
    cout << X.two();
    return 0;
}
```

But I think that incurs an unnecessary v-table lookup on each call to `Y<n>.two()`, right?

Is there any way to share code between the specialized and unspecialized version without abusing inheritance and incurring a v-table lookup call?

Comment: define *abusing* inheritance.

Comment: @SergeyA it seems to me like this variety of problem should be solvable without using inheritance at all, although if there's some solution that uses inheritance but avoids a v-table lookup, that would be ok.

Comment: @SergeyA: OK, I misunderstood.

Comment: Oh, someone already have done CRTP. Nothing to do for me here.

Comment: I think the way code sharing is defined by inheritance does not fit many real world cases. It is incomplete. CRTP improves it a bit. It might be an abuse for pure inheritance, but it is a neat way to think about design in many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `one` method to `mixin` at all. Just have `mixin` with a non-virtual `two` method to share its implementation with derived class `Y` and use CRTP.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Derive>
struct mixin {
    int two() { return ((Derive *)this)->one() * 2; }
};

template <size_t n> struct Y : public mixin <Y<n>> {
    int one() { return 1; }
};

template <> struct Y<1> : public mixin <Y<1>> {
    int one() { return 11; }
};

int main() {
    Y<1> X;
    cout << X.one();
    cout << X.two();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can speciliaze the one method, instead of the class specialization:

```
template <size_t n> struct Y {
  int one() { return 1; }
  int two() { return one() * 2;  }
  int theird(); // declare only for Y<N>
};

template <>
int Y<1>::one() { return 11; }

// only for Y<1>
template <>
int Y<1>::theird() { return one()*two();}
```

Comment: Ah, yes. This would work in this scenario, but I'd like to have methods defined on `Y<1>` that don't exist at all on `Y<n>`.

Comment: You can do it if you declare such methods only and specialize them only for the Y<1>.

Comment: Just to clarify your comment, you mean I could define the method I'd like to exist only for Y<1> on the definition of Y<n>, but then only implement it specialized for Y<1>?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of CRTP, you can also do it the other way round:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <size_t n> struct Y {
    int one() { return 1; }
};

template <> struct Y<1> {
    int one() { return 11; }
};

template <size_t n>
struct mixin : Y<n> {
    int two() { return Y<n>::one() * 2; }
};

int main() {
    mixin<1> X;
    cout << X.one();
    cout << X.two();
    return 0;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
template <class P>
struct mixin : P {
    int two() { return P::one() * 2; }
};

mixin<Y<1>> X;
```